# How to exactly match a word with one regexp?

Tags: python, regex

Using Python 3.9.13.

How can I match an exact word without preceding or trailing character with a simple one regexp expression?

There are answers using the boundary word `\b`. However, according to the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), it can match non word characters.

> `\b`: Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning/end of the string.

For instance, I want to get a match only with the word `cool`, but no match with `#cool` or `cool.`.

```
re.findall(
    pattern=r'\bcool\b', 
    string=" #cool", 
    flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.ASCII
)
---
['cool']
```

Alternative can be listing multiple patterns but it is not clean.

```
re.findall(
    pattern=r'\Acool\Z|\s+cool\s+|^cool\s+|\s+cool\Z', 
    string=" #cool", 
    flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.ASCII
)
---
```

Please advise if there is better and simple one regexp pattern to achieve this.

---

## Update

As answered by [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)

```
re.findall(
    pattern=r'(?<!\S)cool(?!\S)', 
    string=" #cool cool& cool cool\n (cool)", 
    flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.ASCII
)
---
['cool', 'cool']
```

or

```
re.findall(
    pattern=r'(?<=\s|^)cool(?=\s|$)', 
    string=" #cool cool& cool cool\n (cool)", 
    flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.ASCII
)
---
['cool', 'cool']
```

Comment: `(?<!\S)cool(?!\S)`

Answer (score -2):

Use the match function and other regex pattern like this

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\Acool\Z")

print(pattern.findall("cool"))
print(pattern.match("cool"))
```

And then if you want to make it in an if statement like this:

```
if (pattern.match("cool") != None):
    print("cool Matched")
```

Or Based of your question:

```
import re

re.findall(
    pattern=r"\Acool\Z",
    string="cool",
    flags=re.IGNORECASE
)
```